# Is it possible to create a slice in redux-toolkit using only extraReducers and an empty reducers object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following code:

```
export const walkSlice = createSlice({
    name: "walk"
  , initialState
  , reducers: {}
  ,extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      // Change status to loading when API call is pending
      .addCase(fetchWalk.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = cStatusType.Loading;
      })
...
```

When the reducers are set to an empty object, the slice does not seem to appear in Redux state. I only want to use `extraReducers` to handle API calls. I've tested adding an empty reducer eg.

```
reducers: {
    add: (state) => {
      
    },
...
```

This seems to add the slice to the state. Is there a way around this? I don't want unnecessary code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `createSlice` with an empty `reducers` object, yes, but there's no real point to it.  The purpose of `createSlice` *is* to define case reducers inside the `reducers` object, which then generate corresponding action types and action creators.  If you are *only* listening to other action types that were already defined and *only* are using the `extraReducers` field, you should use `createReducer` instead.

Comment: FYI the "builder callback" section in https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation might give readers a wrong impression - which is that you can use either one and it will work. But it looks like createSlice only produces actions in the slice stemming from the "reducer" part.

Comment: As I described above, `reducers` is for _defining_ new action types, and `extraReducers` is for _responding_ to _other_ action types defined elsewhere.  Not sure what I follow what additional point you're trying to make - can you clarify?

Comment: I misunderstood the docs apparently. I assumed that in order to use the "builder callback notation" I have to use "extraReducers" (that builder is not available for the "reducers" section).

Comment: As of RTK 1.9.x, yes, the "builder callback" syntax _only_ exists for `extraReducers`.   In RTK 2.0, we'll be adding something similar-ish to the `reducers` field to let you define thunks inside of `createSlice`.  All that said, I'm still confused about what _you're_ confused about? :)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the "other action types" aspect and was wondering why the slice doesn't contain anything in `.actions` if I use only extraReducers. I somehow got the idea that "extra" refers to the builder syntax, not the differentiation of where actions "belong" to.

Comment: Ah, yeah, it's _exactly_ the "ownership" aspect that is the difference here.